# Dropdown Menu Issues in Chrome - Not Dropping Down Properly

Tags: html, css, navigation, menu

I have made a navbar at the top of my website which contains multiple buttons. One of the buttons right now I added a dropdown menu. It simply uses a unordered list with list items in with a little CSS coding to make it have some colour and actually be hidden until hovered. This works, I have tried it on IE and FF. Both work fine. Now Google Chrome when I try it there, there are some issues.

On hover the items appear which they should. But when I try and click on them they disappear. I've also been on another site and have had this issue though I did not code it in that case. I'm assuming this is a Chrome issue, but I also assume that there is something I can do to fix this on my site.

My question is how do I fix this issue on Chrome (Looking at the code not the browser though)?

Note: If I do a hard refresh (CTRL+SHIFT+R) I am able to hover over the things fine. Once I click on a link or perform a normal refresh again though the issue comes back. Obviously I don't want to have to do a hard refresh to click an item in the dropdown nor would users of the site want to.

Edit: Here is a link to where you can look at the problem on my websites testing area:
[Testing Area](http://fogest.net16.net/test/)

Edit2: Since I'm getting no responses I will include the code.

**index.php:**

---

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
            <link href="navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>      
        <?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
        <?php include("header.php"); ?>
          <p class="content" >Welcome to my homepage! This page will feature a wide range of things from video tutorials to help forums. </p>
          <p class="content" ><em>Remember the site is currently being devopled still! Check out the "<a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>" button on the left if you have any bugs to report.</em></p>
        <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css:**

---

```
b{
    color:#000000;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#666;
}
img{
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
p.welcome {
    text-align:center;
    font-family: “verdana”;
    font-size:1.875em;
    color:white;
    font-weight:900;            
}
p.content {
    font-family: “verdana”;
    font-size:1em;
    color:white;
}
div.main{
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    background:black;
}
div.row1{
width:100%;
}
div.row2{
width:100%;
}
div.row2col1{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:1em;
    color:white;
}
div.row2col2{
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    background-color:brown;
    padding:1em;
    border:15px solid #212121;
}
body{
    background-color:#393635;
    color:white;
}
p.footer{
    text-align:right;
}
.clearFloat{
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**header.php:**

---

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="row1"> <a href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
</div>
        <div class="navMenu">                   
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="videos.php">Videos</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="videolatest.php">Latest Videos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="videotutorial.php">Tutorials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="videogaming.php">Gaming</a></li>
                        <li><a href="videocoding.php">Coding</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <br class="clearFloat" />
        </div>
        <div class="row2col2">
```

**footer.php**

---

```
          </div>
Copyright Fog Productions 2012
</div>
```

Comment: @Fogest - To ensure your question gets the right attention at StackOverflow, can you include the pertinent HTML and CSS for this Chrome issue? (or a link to where the issue can be observed in action)

Comment: If you need anything else added to the post to help with fixing this feel free to ask!

Comment: Added the code hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, a small gap between the anchor and the sub-list is causing it to disappear is causing the list to vanish when you stop briefly hovering over the anchor.

I was able to test this by reducing the positioning of the sub-list by 2px (below) so that it was touching the anchor - therefore not leaving the anchor before hovering over the sub-list.

```
.navmenu li ul {
    top: 30px; /* instead of 32 */
}
```

Comment: I was using 32 to make it perfectly aligned. When at 30 if you look at it closely you can tell it's a little off and not flush with the button. I will try this though and see if that works.

Comment: Wow I just got a chance to try doing this. This fixed the issue. I would never have though that this would have affected it. If you look closely it's now off from the main Video element though that is why I had it at 32 to align it nicely. I guess I will have to just ignore this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your demo site in the Chrome Browser and the menu functioned correctly. I tried several times and could not reproduce the "disappearing menu" issue you mention above (I was able to click on all the menu links)

Is your Chrome up to date? You can view this by clicking on the Wrench icon > About Google Chrome. The most up to date version (at this point) is 18.0xxx

If you are still having issues try disabling all add-ons, clearing your cache and testing it again. To disable add-ons go here: Wrench icon > Settings > Extension tab

Comment: Hmmm well I did make some changes to it if you look at the edits. Maybe I fixed it and I just need to clear my cache.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, though these were not the issue!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it answered :)