# CSS Drop Down Menu not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm new to working with Chrome, I've got the following layout for my page, The CSS menu drop downs will not stay when moving off the top element. http://jsfiddle.net/XxGb8/1/.

The drop down is not working in Chrome, works fine in IE and Firefox. Thanks in advance.

I've looked at other answers, which hint that it might be 
[Dropdown Menu Issues in Chrome - Not Dropping Down Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351825/dropdown-menu-issues-in-chrome-not-dropping-down-properly)

```
#submenu ul li ul {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;(When I change this however the menu still doesnt function correctly{
```

HTML

```
 <div id="container">
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="submenu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Web Design</li>
                            <li>Web Development</li>
                            <li>Illustrations</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>About
                        <ul>
                            <li>News</li>
                            <li>Forum</li>
                            <li>Development Blog</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="links.php">Links</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/support/support.php">Support</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="mailto:webmaster@businessmanager.com">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">

             <div id="sub-content-left">
                <h1>Testing</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, asdasdconsectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, obcaecati incidunt voluptatibus perspiciatis labore quasi beatae ad laboriosam aliquid fuga ullam accusantium sint doloremque possimus cumque veritatis commodi iste hic.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, accusantium, qui, ipsa rem dolores voluptas excepturi officia nisi quas laborum voluptatibus architecto placeat aperiam consequuntur eveniet delectus non voluptates cum? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <div id="homepage-login">
                    <p>Login Form</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="sub-content-right">
                <h2>About..</h2>
                <p>Incidunt, accusantium, qui, ipsa rem dolores voluptas excepturi officia nisi quas laborum voluptatibus architecto placeat aperiam consequuntur eveniet delectus non voluptates cum? Lorem ipsum dolosdsdsddsdr sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, accusantium, qui, ipsa rem dolores voluptas excepturi officia nisi quas laborum voluptatibus architecto placeat aperiam consequuntur eveniet delectus non voluptates cum?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <h3>The End Goal . . .</h3>
                <p>Incidunt, accusantium, qui, ipsa rem dolores voluptas excepturi officia nisi quas laborum voluptatibus architecto placeat aperiam consequuntur eveniet delectus non voluptates cum?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, accusantium, qui, ipsa rem dolores voluptas excepturi officia nisi quas laborum voluptatibus architecto placeat aperiam consequuntur eveniet delectus non voluptates cum?</p>
            </div>

        </div>


    <div id="footer">
            <p>&copy;Testing</p>
        </div>
        </div>

    body {
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #E7EBF2;
}
```

CSS

```
#container{
    margin-top:-10px;
    width:103%;
    margin-left:-15px;
    padding-left:1px;
    min-height:100%;
}
#content{
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#logo {
 display:inline;
    position:fixed;
    padding-left:25px;
}
#menu {
    background:#3B5999;
    padding:10px;
    z-index:100px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    clear: both; 

}
#footer{
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:-10px;
    width:95%;  
    bottom:5px;
    position:relative;
}
#content{

    padding-top:60px;
}
#main{
    float:clear;
}
#sub-content-left{
float:left;
width:74%;
min-height:100%;
padding:5px;
}
#sub-content-right{
float:left;
width:20%;
min-height:100%;
padding:5px;
}
#submenu a{
 color:inherit;
    background:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#submenu a:hover{
    font-stretch:extra-expanded;
}

#homepage-login{

}
#submenu {
    left:45%;
    margin-left:-240px;
    width:480px;
    background:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius:10px;
    clear: both; 
    z-index:100;
    position: absolute;
}
#submenu ul  {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;

}
#submenu ul li {
    font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
/*    border-right:1px #3B5999 solid;
    border-left:1px #3B5999 solid;*/
}

#submenu ul li:hover {
    background: #3B5999;
    color:#fff ;
}
#submenu ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
#submenu ul li ul li {
    background: #3B5999;
    display: block;
    color:#fff ;
    border-bottom:1px #3B5999 solid;
    border-left:1px #3B5999 solid;
    border-right:1px #3B5999 solid;
    border-top:1px #3B5999 solid;
}
#submenu ul li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
#submenu ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #3B5999;
}
#submenu>ul>li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've used an invalid value for the `z-index` property - it only accepts an integer value but you've used `100px`

```
#menu {
    z-index: 100; /* you had 100px */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XxGb8/3/

Comment: Thanks, for your help, late night coding is always a bad idea :)Appreciate it.